# Typescript Union Type on HTMLInputElement

Tags: typescript, dom

I'm trying to do the following

```js
let username: String | HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector('#username')
if (username.reportValidity()) {
  username = username.value
  verify({ username })
}
```

but I get this error

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'String | HTMLInputElement'.
```

but the value property does exist on HTMLInputElement

What type info do I need so I can reassign username to the field's value

Thanks

Comment: You can check the type before username.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use type guard before accessing the value

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards

But reassign username from HTMLInputElement to String is not a good practice. It is better to have another variable to store the username value

```
let username: String | HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector('#username')
if (username.reportValidity() && username instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
  username = username.value
  verify({ username })
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out

I can do

```js
let username: String | HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector('#username')
if (username.reportValidity()) {
  username = (username as HTMLInputElement).value
  verify({ username })
}
```

Comment: This `as` is not always runtime safe. It will have runtime error if document.querySelector function dose not return u HTMLInputElement